# asp listview... When is datasource instance created?

Tags: asp.net, listview

I have a lisview with an object datasource defined as:

```
<asp:ListView 
              ID="ListView1" 
              runat="server"
              OnItemDeleting="ComentariosListView_OnItemDeleting"
              DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1">

<asp:ObjectDataSource 
         ID="ObjectDataSource1" 
         runat="server" 
         DataObjectTypeName="Gedas.GestImp.GUI.WebComponents.Expedientes.ComentarioListViewItem" 
         DeleteMethod="Delete" 
         OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" 
         SelectMethod="FindAll" 
         TypeName="Gedas.GestImp.GUI.WebComponents.Expedientes.ComentariosListViewDS">
```

In the Page_Load I try to access its dataSource properti but it's null.

```
ComentariosListViewDS ds = (ComentariosListViewDS)ListView1.DataSource;
```

Why is it null? When is it created? How can I declare the listview to have a datasource instance created?

Comment: You can handle its `DataBound` event..

Answer (score 0):

Databind happens on [PreRenderComplete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) unless you call it in the codebehind earlier.